# Open Graph publish limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a Facebook Open Graph action for my app, that has a potential of being published many times for each user (e.g, each time a user listens to a song on the site).
For some users, I may have hundreds of such actions per session or per day.

Question is - does Facebook pose limits on how many times an app publishes Open Graph actions? Obviously, Facebook will not show all those actions on feeds, and will probably show just the first ones, if any. But is it the application's responsibility to throttle the publishing, or is it encouraged to publish the real amount of actions?

If the app should throttle, what is a reasonable number of actions per user per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish everything. We will take care of the aggregation.

Comment: Cool! Thanks Paul. I like this approach much better, not only because it makes it more natural and easier on my side, but because it really makes Open Graph much more interesting in the long run.. Kudos to you guys @ Facebook.